# Windows 10 1607 LTSB no driver for Geforce RTX 4070 Ti

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-10-v1607

We have a pc with Windows 10 1607 LTSB, and for this OS we need the "standard" NVIDIA drivers since the DCH drivers are not compatible with the OS.

For the 4070Ti, there are currently no standard drivers available, only DCH.

Can anyone comment on how long it typically takes before the standard driver is available?

Or alternatively, could we update Windows in any way to allow installation of DCH drivers? (With the side note that this is a PC that is currently being used in a research lab and we preferably don't reinstall all required software + settings for connected measurement devices)

Comment: "Can anyone comment on how long it typically takes before the standard driver is available?" - You might be waiting awhile.  Nvidia does not release drivers for unsupported versions of operating systems.  Since you have a newer product, the drivers that do exist, might not be updated to support newer hardware. There isn't an upgrade path to a newer version since you are running a LTSB Enterprise installation.  I could be wrong, downloading a support newer version of Windows 10 LTSC Enterprise, and mounting the ISO could provide you the option to upgrade to it.  LTSC replaced LTSB by the way

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the response, "downloading a support newer version of Windows 10 LTSC Enterprise, and mounting the ISO could provide you the option to upgrade to it" I read about this on a questionable source, if someone could confirm this works, and we could install the DCH driver after update I'll give it a try.

Comment: You certainly will be prompted to upgrade to the newer version.  However, the LTSC were designed for extended life cycle supportability, by Microsoft.  What I don't know is if you will be given the option to essentially "keep everything" or be force to perform a clean install.  **I am confused, my suggestion, essentially confirms your source.**

Comment: You are right, sorry for the confusion, your suggestion confirms the source. The only question remaining is "can I keep everything".

Comment: My suggestion? Load the original ISO into a VM, install it, then mount the new ISO into the VM and test the upgrade. You might wait awhile before finding somebody with access to a LTSB ISO and a LTSC ISO with enough knowlege to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We tried upgrading a VM and could keep all installed software without any problem. New driver installed and everything works as expected!

Comment: I'd like to add for posterity that the INF files for some older versions of the DCH driver can be modded, to allow it to be installed on Windows 1607. More details can be found on this forum post: https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/windows-10-1607-516-94-driver-for-gtx-980.444247/